# Multiple "Format String Issue" warnings in JSONKit.m after upgrading to PhoneGap 2.0 on iOS

Tags: xcode, cordova

We just upgraded to PhoneGap/Cordova 2.0 on iOS, but we're seeing multiple warnings in JSONKit.m.

There are two classes of warnings: (1) "Format String Issue" and (2) "Semantic Issue."

Here is an example of the "Format String Issue":

```
/Users/macuser/Documents/CordovaLib/Classes/JSON/JSONKit.m:745:180: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

Here is an example of the "Semantic Issue":

```
/Users/macuser/Documents/CordovaLib/Classes/JSON/JSONKit.m:2600:11: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
```

We're on Lion, Xcode 4.4.

Any clues why this warnings are happening now whereas they didn't before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a user on Google Groups:

Xcode 4.4 uses an updated compiler which is more strict. It's harmless
(for now) but this issue was fixed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1164

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find how to remove the warnings: 
https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues/79

Answer (score 2):

This is [JSONKit](https://github.com/IgorFedorchuk/JSONKitWithoutXcode4Warnings) files without xcode 4.4 warnings